# How to call TestResult method in other inherited classes. TestResult is defined in ITest class and call in Email and other Test classes

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

[image]

Please help me in calling this TestResult variable

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `AssertResult` has `public` accessibility modifier

`public class AssertResult {... }`

Comment: @AliceBush you're welcome, if its solved your issue, would you be able to select this answer as the solution please. Thanks